# Why aren't some technically serializable input properties serializable?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Serializable property is defined as:

- When you set a property of the element, it will be reflected in serialization queries such as `getAttribute` and you can see the changes in DOM Inspector
- When you get the `.innerHTML` of the element's parentnode, the returned html string will contain all the serializable properties as their attribute counterparts

I have made a page that looks like it's reliably printing a table of all serializable properties of the `input` element in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/tEVLp/16/.
Custom properties are never serializable, so in firefox `webkitSpeech` etc are not serializable. Test in chrome for best results.

All booleans are `true` because serialization of a `false` property would be the absence of the attribute which is a false negative in the test.

So my question is, why are not properties such as `.value` and `.checked` serializable?

Technically, both are serializable. `.value` is just a string and the browser has no problems with serializing other boolean properties, such as `.readOnly` and `.disabled`.

My best guess is that since `.defaultValue` serializes to `"value"`-attribute and `.defaultChecked` serializes to `"checked"`-attribute, there would be a conflict and thus the 
`.value` and `.checked` cannot be serialized. In that case, why are the `defaultX` ones chosen for these and not the ones that reflect the more useful current `.value` and `.checked` states?

Comment: In Firefox, the "type" attribute shows up with "title" in the attribute key column. Weird.

Comment: @Pointy the test is assuming that the newly created attribute is last in the attributes list... turns out `type` is for some reason moved to the first position in firefox. See http://jsfiddle.net/tEVLp/14/ for the logs

Comment: The "lang" attribute is also strange like that.

Comment: @Pointy heh actually many of them are like that, I have adjusted that in my question. Workaround would be storing them in an array and comparing `attr` objects for equality to find out which one changed .

Comment: It's really bizarre; the "value" attribute is there in the list (in the console); how/when does it get there?  The length of the list is 0 before the loop that sets the properties, and it only changes by 1 when properties are (successfully) added. I need some coffee.

Comment: @Pointy `.defaultValue` maps to the `"value"`-attribute, see the last paragraph. Changing `.defaultValue` indeed shows up in dom inspectors and `.getAttribute` etc. This conflict would be obvious answer to my first question but I also wanted to know if there is a reason for choosing `.defaultValue` over `.value` mapping.

Comment: I would assume this is how it is for elements the user can interact with. The internal value or state of such an element can be changed during its life time (by the user) but the other attributes can't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Specification for input elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html) defines the exact behaviour. Start reading from [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) (before that, the DOM interface, attributes and types are defined).

Concise summary (`value` is defined similarly to `checked`, so for brevity, I'm going to explain `value` only).

The "property" `value` reflects [value <sup>def</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#concept-fe-value),
the "attribute" `value` reflects the [value content attribute <sup>def</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#dom-input-value).

- The attribute defines the default value property <sup>([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#attr-input-value))</sup>. This value is also [reflected <sup>def</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflect) by the `defaultValue` property ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#dom-input-defaultvalue)).
- When the value attribute is set, then the value property changes ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#attr-input-value)) *.

That was worded very concisely. I've skipped an important detail. The specification is very clear at this point, so I'll just quote the [**dirty value flag**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#concept-input-value-dirty-flag) section:

> Each input element has a boolean **dirty value flag**. The dirty value
>   flag must be initially set to false when the element is created, and
>   must be set to true whenever the user interacts with the control in a
>   way that changes the value.
>
> The value content attribute gives the default value of the input
>   element. When the value content attribute is added, set, or removed,
>   if the control's dirty value flag is false, the user agent must set
>   the value of the element to the value of the value content attribute,
>   if there is one, or the empty string otherwise, and then run the
>   current value sanitization algorithm, if one is defined.

Comment: Excellent, I can demonstrate this here. http://jsfiddle.net/Psb2Z/1/ After you make the flag dirty, set attribute has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

`value` and `checked` properties do not correspond to HTML attributes so they cannot be serialized to HTML. As to why a `defaultX` property maps to the `x` attribute, I'm not sure. The alternative, a property `x` mapping to the `x` attribute and having another property such as `currentX` to represent the current value, seems slightly less intuitive because in general a script is going to need the current value more often than the default value.

Comment: Yes, the `"value"` and `"checked"`-attributes actually map to `.defaultValue` and `.defaultChecked`. So there would be a conflict. So the really interesting question is why choose these over the current ones. I think Felix Kling's theory is pretty interesting.

Comment: @Esailija: Felix's theory matches my long-held assumption, although I've never seen a definitive explanation. I feel I'm probably missing something obvious.