# how to change text box value with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change the value of the textboxes when the user clicks the submit button with Jquery.  I tried it with

```
$('textbox').val('Changed Value');
```

and

```
$('#dsf').val('Changed Value');
```

but neither method worked.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>serializeArray demo</title>
  <style>
  body, select {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  form {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  p {
    color: red;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  b {
    color: blue;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Results:</b> <span id="results"></span></p>
<form>
  <select name="single">
    <option>Single</option>
    <option>Single2</option>
  </select>
  <select name="multiple" multiple="multiple">
    <option selected="selected">Multiple</option>
    <option>Multiple2</option>
    <option selected="selected">Multiple3</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check1" id="ch1">
  <label for="ch1">check1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check2" checked="checked" id="ch2">
  <label for="ch2">check2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1">
  <label for="r1">radio1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="radio2" id="r2">
  <label for="r2">radio2</label>


  <input type="submit"  value="s1" id="ch">

  <input type="submit"  value="szv" id="cd" > 

  <input type="text"   value = "abc"  id = "dsf" > 

  <input type="text"   value = "abc"  id = "dsxzcv"  > 

</form>

<script>
  function showValues() {
    var fields = $( ":input" ).serializeArray();
    $( "#results" ).empty();
    jQuery.each( fields, function( i, field ) {
      $( "#results" ).append( field.value + " " );
    });
  }

  $( ":checkbox, :radio" ).click( showValues );
  $( "select" ).change( showValues );

  $(#ch1).val("adfsadf") ;

  showValues();

  $(‘:submit’).click(function () {

   $(‘:submit’).val() = "dasf" ;

   $('textbox').val('Changed Value');

 //$('#dsf').val('Changed Value');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Be sure to disable the default event on the submit button if you are going to use it to detect the click event. e.preventDefault();

Comment: There is no 'textbox' element.  Also, you're using improper quote marks for the prior code.  That is likely causing your script to error out and fail.

Comment: Cant believe that such a simple question which has actually some small syntax error gets so big response of 11 answers anf also give a golden badge !! Simply wow !!

Comment: If you're seeing this now looking, suggest you also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value).  Attr saved my day where val did not.

Answer (score 28):

You could just use this very simple way

```
<script>
  $(function() {

    $('#cd').click(function() {
      $('#dsf').val("any thing here");
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

If `.val()` is not working, I would suggest you to use the `.attr()` attribute

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("your_button").on("click", function() {
      $("your_textbox").val("your value");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: But it does not change the textbox

Answer (score 3):

Document ready function was missing thats why the code was not working.
For example:

```
$(function(){

 $('#button1').click(function(){
   $('#txtbox1').val('Changed Value');
 });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

**You may try following this:**

You forgot to add quote :  `$(#ch1).val("adfsadf") ;`

This supposed to be :  `$('#ch1').val("adfsadf") ;`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function ) {
    $('element').val('Changed Value');
    $('element').html('Changed Value');
    $('element').text('Changed Value');
});
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    element.value = 'Changed Value';
    element.innerHTML = 'Changed Value';
    element.textContent = 'Changed Value'; // All browsers except IE. For IE: innerText
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy :

```
 $('#email').val(YourNewValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use like this on dropdown change
$("#assetgroupSelect").change(function(){
    $("#idValue").val($this.val());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This will change the value when button is clicked:

```
<script>
  jQuery(function() {
    $('#b11').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var name = "hello";
      $("#t1").val(name);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fztd/1/):

```
$(function() {
  $('#cd').click(function () {
    $('#dsf').val('Changed Value');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cd').click(function() {
  $(this).val('dasf');  // update the value of submit button
  $('#dsf').val('Changed Value') // update the text input value
});
```

`textbox` is not a valid selector.

Also, when you hit the submit button it will submit the form as default behavior. So don't forget to stop default form submission.

Better if you do like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {

  // write all your codes

  return false; // Prevent default form submission
});
```

Don't forget to user jQuery DOM ready `$(function() { .. });`

Comment: What about the other problems?

Comment: @Daedalus answer stick with the issue OP asked. OP need to figure out something, should do some study.SO is not place to show detail tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you simply do like this hope will help you

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

  $("#cd").click(function () {   

    $('#dsxzcv').val("Changed_Value");   

})
})
```

here you can see the demo

http://jsbin.com/dolebana/1

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to add a click event to a submit input you will need to prevent the normal flow that this will do that is submit the form.

You can also use `$(document).ready()`

But since you have your script tag at the end of the page the DOM is already loaded.

To prevent the default you will need something like this:

```
$("form").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dsf").val("changed value")

})
```

If the element wasn't a submit input it will be as simple as

```
$("#cd").click(function(){
    $("#dsf").val("changed value")

})
```

See this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rsvz/)

Answer (score 0):

Use ready event of document :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* the click code */ });
```

And it is better to use bind method for event handeling. because you don't want to call click action in every load of page

```
  $(':submit').bind('click' , function () { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the text of "input",use:

```
     `$("#inputId").val("what you want to put")`
```

and if you want to change the text in "label","span","div", you can use

```
     `$("#containerId").text("what you want to put")`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .form-cus {
        width: 200px;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
    }
        .form-cus .putval, .form-cus .getval {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .form-cus .putval {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0;
            color: transparent !important;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            border: 0px;
            outline: 0 none;
        }
            .form-cus .putval::selection {
                color: transparent;
                background: lightblue;
            }
</style>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-cus">
    <input class="putval form-control" type="text" id="input" maxlength="16" oninput="xText();">
    <input class="getval form-control" type="text" id="output" maxlength="16">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function xText() {
        var x = $("#input").val();
        var x_length = x.length;
        var a = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < x_length; i++) {
            a += "x";
        }
        $("#output").val(a);
     }
    $("#input").click(function(){
     $("#output").trigger("click");
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function xText() {
  var x = $("#input").val();
  var x_length = x.length;
  var a = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < x_length; i++) {
    a += "x";
  }
  $("#output").val(a);
}
```

```css
.form-cus {width: 200px;margin: auto;position: relative;}
.form-cus .putval, .form-cus .getval {width: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
.form-cus .putval {position: absolute;left: 0px;top:0; height:100%; color: transparent;background: transparent;border: 0px;outline: 0 none;}
.form-cus .putval::selection {color: transparent;background: lightblue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Input Number or Strong Mouse Click is Hidden... </p>
<div class="form-cus">
  <input class="putval" type="text" id="input" maxlength="16" oninput="xText();" placeholder="Input Text" />
  <input class="getval" type="text" id="output" maxlength="16" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate as to why your solutions should work and what the OP was doing wrong. Just pasting code doesn't clarify the doubt in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button-id").click(function() {
      $('#text').val("create");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.