# Text input populated with jQuery .val() is visible but does not appear in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have used jQuery to populate the value of a text input.

```
$(".textInput").val("foo");
```

When I look at the page, "foo" appears in the input, however, when I inspect the element in Chrome, "foo" is nowhere to be seen in the HTML.

Also, I have done something similar with a  element using .text() and it worked fine (despite the fact that jQuery's docs say you can only use .val()).

Comment: It is impossible to see an element that is not in the DOM.... It is also impossible to help you without any link to a test page...

Comment: is this being added to the dom *after* the initial load? it won't be in the in the mark-up if it is on a document.ready call

Comment: If the value is showing in the control, it is being populated correctly. .text should only be used to populate label elements.

Comment: What do you mean by "nowhere to be seen in the html"? JavaScript updates the DOM, not the html source.

Comment: If you type in a text input and look at the DOM you also won't see it in the element.

Comment: you can see it in the textbox if you enable [shadow dom](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/), but I don't think that's what you're going for.

Comment: I found a relevant answer  in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value). For some reason the change is not reflecting in Chrome's inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to view the generated source.
This is generated after the dom tree is executed.

You can view generated source by using tools such as [Fidder](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)