# Reading html() after settings val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery to update the value of a text input and, while reading the `value` back in the same way shows that the `.val()` is updated, dumping the `.html()` doesn't reflect the change. A coworker has offered a work around, but I'm not sure why the original doesn't work.

```
var new_form_resp = $('<div><input value="OLD" type="text"></div>');
new_form_resp.find("input").val("NEW")
// new_form_resp.find("input").attr("value", "NEW") does work

console.log(new_form_resp.html()); // doesn't have the value
console.log(new_form_resp.find("input").val()); // but it does have the value set...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1pzt71z6/

The answer seems to be here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873770/3208419

Comment: val() gets/sets the value of the value attribute of the input field

Comment: check your console buddy its giving the right result, `<input value="OLD" type="text">` & `NEW`

Comment: The point is that is should show `<input value="NEW" type="text">` & `NEW`.