# How to set value of input number with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set the value of an input element using jQuery.

HTML:
`<input id="id_year" name="year" type="number">`

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var year = $("#id_year");
    year.datepicker({
        format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
        viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: "years"
    });
    year.on('changeDate', function(ev){
        year.attr('value',ev.date.getFullYear());
    });
});
```

If the input type is `text`, it works. But I have to use `number` as input type.

How can I set the input value with jQuery or regular JavaScript?

## Important notes

I tried to use `year.val(ev.date.getFullYear());` but It didn't work.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `.attr()` to set the value *property* of *any* form elements, you should be using `.val()`. (As an aside, why is there a space at the beginning of the format?)

Comment: try with year.val(ev.date.getFullYear());

Comment: @KinjalGohil I tried with `year.val(ev.date.getFullYear());`, but It doesn't work!

Comment: Seems val can have issues sometimes?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right, just the definition of datepicker is wrong, change

```
format: " yyyy"
```

to :

```
dateFormat: "yy"
```

(If you are using jquery-ui datepicker)

[DEMO Here](https://jsfiddle.net/juza5dn2/1/)

Comment: Your works, my script not.
Perhaps because I am using bootstrap-datepicker.js
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Using `ev.date.getFullYear()` I get a valid year number. I do not understand why I can not change the input value. If the type is "text" it works, but not if the type is "number".

Comment: I chose to use the jquery-ui library. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
year.val(ev.date.getFullYear());
```

to get the value: `var yearValue = year.val();`

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `val` function.

You can write your code as this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var year = $("#id_year");
    year.datepicker({
        format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
        viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: "years"
    });
    year.on('changeDate', function(ev){
        console.log("ssds");
        $(this).val(ev.date.getFullYear());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var year = $("#id_year");
    year.datepicker({
        format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
        viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: "years",
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
          console.log(dateText);
          var startDate = new Date(dateText);
          year.val(startDate.getFullYear());
          console.log(year.val());
        }
    });
   /* year.on('changeDate', function(ev){
        console.log("ssds");
        year.val(ev.date.getFullYear());
      console.log(year.val());
    });*/
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<input id="id_year" name="year" type="number">
```