# How to get HTML string of dynamically changed element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parent = $('#foo');
  parent.find('#bar').val('hi');
  console.log(parent.prop('outerHTML'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <input type='text' id="bar" value="" />
</div>
```

I have a container div with child input element, the initial value is empty, after that I change it's value using jQuery and try to get the changed html string using .prop('outerHTML'). However it returns:

```
<div id="foo"><input type="text" id="bar" value=""></div>
```

I need to return it as:

```
<div id="foo"><input type="text" id="bar" value="hi"></div>
```

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.attr()` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parent = $('#foo');
  parent.find('#bar').attr('value', 'hi');
  console.log(parent.prop('outerHTML'));

  $('#txt').text('hello');
  console.log($('#par').find('#txt').prop('outerHTML'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <input type='text' id="bar" value="" />
</div>

<div id="par">
  <textarea id='txt'></textarea>
</div>
```

For more details - visit following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value).

Comment: For more info on why to use this you can refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value)

Comment: @George Thank you. Edited.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks for the help, I am surprised this question was never asked before :)

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli My pleasure, have a great day.

Comment: @Kinduser just a question! How to do the same thing if there was a textarea instead of input ?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli Exactly the same, just replace `input` tag with `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: @Kinduser but does <textarea> support attribute value = "" ?

Comment: @BiswasKhayargoli There was some conflict between val and setting it into `textarea`. I've provided you some working solution on it. Instead of `val()`, you can use `text()` here. It will change the `textarea` content dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use direct attrbite change, not element value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parent = $('#foo');
  parent.find('#bar').attr('value', 'hi');
  console.log(parent.prop('outerHTML'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">
  <input type='text' id="bar" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!, but I will have to mark the above answer correct as he did it first :)

Comment: Not a problem at all :)))

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var parent = $('#foo');
  parent.find('#bar').attr('value','hi');
  console.log(parent.prop('outerHTML'));
});
```