# How do I programmatically trigger <select> onChange in React component with plain DOM Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a simple React component:

```
state = {
  value: '',
};

render() {
  return <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}>
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
  </select>;
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    value: e.target.value,
  });
  console.log('Handling Change!!')
};
```

I want to be able to trigger the event handler *programmatically* via ordinary javascript or, in this example, jQuery.

```
$select = $('select');
$select.val('1');
// then
$select.trigger('change');
// or
$select.trigger('input');
```

But none of these trigger the `onChange` handler in the React component, and therefore the state doesn't get updated.

My question: How can I trigger the `onChange` handler using the DOM and Javascript?

**[edit]**

To clarify a bit further, I am mounting the React Component like this:

```
el = document.createElement('div')
ReactDOM.render(MySelect, el)

$select = $(el).find('select');
$select.val('1');
// then
$select.trigger('change');
// or
$select.trigger('input');
```

Comment: This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for?

Comment: @FrankerZ The problem I'm trying to solve is that I have a non-React codebase that uses jQuery to query and test a UI's behaviour, and now I would like to 'reactify' the codebase, _using the same tests_.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering my own question, for posterity.

The issue, it turned out, was twofold. But first, some background:

**React Events**

The React event system listens for native DOM events by delegating to the root node. I.e. it doesn't attach listeners to each element with `onChange`, but just listens on the root document *for events that bubble up* through the DOM.

For those familiar with jQuery delegated events, this would be analogous to something like

```
$(document).on('change', '.my-select', callback)
```

**jQuery Events**

Secondly, jQuery itself somewhat 'overrides' the DOMs native event bubbling with its own system, which is how you can throw around custom events.

#The solution...#

As mentioned, I had 2 problems, and hence 2 solutions:

##**First**##

Because of jQuery using its own event system, events fired with

```
$(select).trigger('change')
```

will not reach React's root event listener. So we go native with...

```
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {bubbles: true}));
```

...but that's still not enough.

##**Second**##

DOM events bubble up from the element to the document root. *BUT notice that I never attached my element to the document!!* The `change` event bubbles up to... nowhere! Again, it never reaches the React event listener *registered on the document*.

If I add my element to the DOM like this:

```
el = document.createElement('div')
ReactDOM.render(MySelect, el)
document.body.appendChild(el) // <-- attach to DOM
```

*Now* the event reaches the React event listener, and the original `onChange` handler in my component is fired.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across something similar.

*ps. I found the documentation in this reactjs file helpful in understanding the React event system: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-dom/src/events/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js*

Comment: This is a very clear breakdown of the problems and their solutions. It's really helpful!

Comment: There is also this related question, which provides a more general reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438258/set-react-input-field-value-from-javascript-or-jquery