# Can't fill input with javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I'm trying to fill inputs on https://account.protonmail.com/login with javascript.

First navigate to https://account.protonmail.com/login and run the following javascript in devtools:

```
document.querySelector('#username').value = 'MyUser'
document.querySelector('#password').value = 'MyPassword'
```

And the form is filled:

[image]

But when I click on "Sign in", the values are gone:

[image]

How can I keep the values when I click on "Sign in"?

Comment: It does work, https://jsfiddle.net/41qgt39v/1/, so the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @JaredFarrish You don't understand this question and you haven't run the same test as I did.

Comment: try triggering oninput or onchange to run whatever is setting the values elsewhere

Comment: You mean you didn't adequately explain the issue.

Comment: @JaredFarrish see if it's clear by now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Proton Account page you linked is based on React, according to its source code. React (like many other frameworks) listens for specific events to know whether or not a user has changed values in form fields.

Fortunately, answerers in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60378508/269970) were able to leverage a simple function for this same functionality, which you can re-use to complete the fields and trigger the appropriate events & validation logic. Your code would look something like this:

```
function changeValue(input,value){

    var nativeInputValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
      window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
      "value"
    ).set;
    nativeInputValueSetter.call(input, value);

    var inputEvent = new Event("input", { bubbles: true });
    input.dispatchEvent(inputEvent);
}

changeValue(document.querySelector('#username'), 'MyUser');
changeValue(document.querySelector('#password'), 'MyPassword');
```

This allows the field validation to be passed for me when running this code in the developer console within the latest release of Chrome.