# JavaScript Input does not change after setting it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a problem regarding filling out an input field with JavaScript.

The reson i try using javascript for this, is i want my flutter android app to open the website as an webview and fill out the input fields.

For testing i run my javascript code in chrome as a script snippet.

I am trying to fill out the input fields of this Webseite :
https://topup.klarna.com/stw_dusseldorf,
but if i use
`document.getElementById("cs-card-number").value = "12345";`
the change goes away if i interact with the website;

I tried triggering the input Event, but it did not work either.

I even tried recreating the same input event as it would be triggered if i manuly typ something in

```
var event = new InputEvent('input');
 event.value = "1";
//event.isTrusted = true
//Object.defineProperty(event, 'isTrusted', {writable: false, value: true});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'bubbles', {writable: false, value: true});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'cancelBubble', {writable: false, value: false});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'cancelable', {writable: false, value: false});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'composed', {writable: false, value: true});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'currentTarget', {writable: false, value: document});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'data', {writable: false, value: "1"});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'dataTransfer', {writable: false, value: null});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'defaultPrevented', {writable: false, value: false});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'detail', {writable: false, value: 0});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'eventPhase', {writable: false, value: 3});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'inputType', {writable: false, value: "insertText"});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'isComposing', {writable: false, value: false});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'path', {writable: false, value: [$("input#cs-card-number-confirm"), $("div#cs-card-number-confirm__text-wrapper"), $("div#cs-card-number-confirm__container"), $("label"), $("div#cs-card-number-confirm__root"), $("div"), $("div.sc-keyyzf.glhkcc"), $("div.sc-fjdhpx.huktqi"), $("div.sc-iwskbi.hwpiky"), $("div.sc-brqgnp.doeca"), $("div.sc-jwbwvp.efkmfx"), $("div#root"), $("body"), $("html"), document, Window]});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'returnValue', {writable: false, value: true});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'sourceCapabilities', {writable: false, value: null});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'srcElement', {writable: false, value: ele});
Object.defineProperty(event, 'target', {writable: false, value: ele});
event.type= "input"

document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Also have tried using

```
document.getElementById("cs-card-number").setAttribute("value", "1234");
```

I am out of ideas how to do this.
If somebody knew how to do this, it would be a great help.

Comment: did you try set attribute? : ```document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('value', test);```

Comment: yes have tried that too

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? What exactly does "interact with the website" mean?

Comment: yea checked the console no errors. With interact i mean hovering with the mouse over the input fields.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438258/set-react-input-field-value-from-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Thank you the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66329563/17995477 from you suggestion Question worked. Thank you