# Data is not Display at the textboxes using Asp.net ajax

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax

when I click the edit button. editable data will be passing into relevant textboxes for editing. but data is not displaying. what i tried so far i attached below.

> Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees)); an object
>   reference required for non-static field

**this is a button**

```
  {
     "sTitle": "Edit",
     "mData": "id",
     "render": function (mData, type, row, meta) {
      return '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" 
      onclick="get_category_details(' + mData + ')">Edit</button>';
   }
```

**if i click the edit button id will be successfully passing to get_category_details method.then post to the edit_return.aspx/doSome page
but data is not retrieved.i think get the error Edit_retun.aspx.**

```
 function get_category_details(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'edit_return.aspx/doSome',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: "{id: '" + id + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {                            

                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                    isNew = false
                    id = data.id     
                    $('#fname').val(data.fname);
                    $('#age').val(data.age);               

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);            
                }

            });
        }
```

**Edit_retun.aspx**

```
public class Employee
        {

            public string id { get; set; }
            public string fname { get; set; }
            public string age { get; set; }
        }

 [WebMethod]
            public static string doSome(int id)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
                string sql = "select * from record where id='" + id + "'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

                employees = dt.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => new Employee()
                        {
                            id = x.Field<int>("id").ToString(),
                            fname = x.Field<string>("name"),
                            age = x.Field<int>("age").ToString(),
                        }).ToList();
                Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees));
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees);
            }
```

**HTML FORM**

```
  <form  id="frmProject" runat="server">
            <div>
                <label class="form-label">First Name</label>     
               <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control"  required />

            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="left">
             <label class="form-label">Age</label>
                <input type="text" id="age" name="age" class="form-control"  required />
            </div>
            <div> 
               <input type="button" id="b1" value="add" class="form-control" onclick="addProject()" />

            </div      
        </form>
```

Comment: add this to method top  [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

Comment: ScriptMethod namespace error sir

Comment: Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employees)); Response keyword getting error sir an object reference required for non-static field. how to write in proper way if you write it . it is more helpful for me.

Comment: Why are you using Response.Write when you are returning the JSON response? Namespce for ScriptMethod is System.Web.Script.Services.

Comment: it used to retrieve data to index.aspx ajax success function.is there any thing wrong on that

Comment: just comment that line, only return statement is more than sufficient for sending data back to ajax call.

Comment: i just commented and sending data but no error displayed but data is not displaying into the textboxes

Comment: Can you please try alert (data.d);   in success part of the ajax.

Comment: thank you sir for your kind help data is successfully came to alert (data.d); if i click the edit button but why data is not passing to the relevant textboxes

Comment: please check on ajex part  sir

Comment: change this  add return false; i.e. onclick="get_category_details(' + mData + '); return false;"

Comment: i changed sir but it is not working

Comment: can you please add your html/aspx code in the question so we can review.

Comment: [WebMethod]
    public List<Employee> doSome(int id)
    {
        // do your task 
        // return employees without serialized. in ajax response you will get list of employee object array.
        return employees;
    }

Comment: sir add the HTML form above please check sir.how can i  return employees without serialized. in ajax response you will get list of employee object array

Comment: sir there..............................

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873721/jquery-val-change-doesnt-change-input-value/11873775#11873775

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `Response.Write` in a `static` method. Your `doSome` method need to be a `non-static` method. Or you can remove `Response.write` from your method as it is not needed here i guess.

Comment: thanks sir i can get data in to ajex function i couldn't transform in to the relavent textboxs can you check the ajex success function above code

Answer (score 0):

```
 [WebMethod]
    public List<Employee> doSome(int id)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=.; Initial Catalog = jds; Integrated Security= true;");
        string sql = "select * from record where id='" + id + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        employees = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => new Employee()
                {
                    id = x.Field<int>("id").ToString(),
                    fname = x.Field<string>("name"),
                    age = x.Field<int>("age").ToString(),
                }).ToList();
        return employees;
    }

Your List<Employee> will be serialize automatically no need to serialize.
In ajax success 
  $.ajax({

            success: function(data){
          data=data.d;
     // now data is JavaScript array of employee object 
},

        });
```

Comment: check full code. i think you are unable to get response from web method , i have solve the return of object type from web service and catching it in ajax success

Comment: console.log(data);  i didn't retrieve any data sir ajax succes

Comment: unknown web method dosome parameter name method name error display when i click edit button

Comment: in $.ajax() call only success param is in my code. in your code replace success method only by my success code and in webservice file check // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: your service file should be edit_return.asmx webservice file but you are using edit_return.aspx which is wrong check once in       $.ajax({
                               url: 'edit_return.aspx/doSome',)

Comment: result will displayed undefined

Comment: [object Object] console.log undefined