# jquery .html() does not reflect actual html; google chrome 24.0.1312.57

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

jQuery 1.9.1 or later, Chrome 24 on osx 10.8.2.

I'm having trouble getting Chrome to select a given value in a select list, and that setting `obj.val('foo')` was not working whereas `$("option[value='foo']",obj).prop("selected",true)` is working.

I'm getting mixed results between different browsers (ie, chrome, firefox) running on windows and mac. mostly that

```
 obj.val('foo')
```

is not currently working on mac chrome only. This is crazy!

I noticed that if I look at the .html() of the object, it does not show which item is selected, even though reading the val() property reports it properly. Which is to say, I'm expecting to (but not) see something like

```
<option value="bucket" selected="selected">bucket</option>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frumbert/a4RzY/

Is this a bug in chrome's implementation of innerHTML() (which http://api.jquery.com/html/ states is being used) ?

Comment: Change `.prop()` to `.attr()` and it'll work.

Comment: @Blender prop() is now used in latest versions.

Comment: @AspiringAqib: `.prop()` doesn't replace `.attr()`. They do different things.

Comment: @frumbert, `innerHTML` does not reflect the `value` attribute, it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: well, @Blender yeah! but we can use `removeAttr` before using `prop` ;) if you understand. Well, i use `prop` like that. :D

Comment: @AspiringAqib: I'm not too sure what you mean by that

Comment: Read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778123/why-arent-some-technically-serializable-input-properties-serializable) - it is about `input`s, not `select`s but you should get the idea of why some DOM properties are not serializable and that you should be using the DOM instead of reading string representations of it.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté In this exact case I wasn't interested in the string representation of the DOM, however I can think of recent cases where I use `.html()` to store what I normally accept to be the current version of a DOM object, e.g. an entire div's contents. I'll have to watch that next time. I understand (now) the difference between an objects attributes and its properties; the difference that `.innerHTML()` means. Setting something as 'selected' by property isn't the same as setting an attribute that says its selected. Hence the common confusion between `prop` and `attr` I guess.

Comment: also, @Blender, tried changing `.prop()` to `.attr()` and it worked in Chrome ... and broke IE