# Is it possible to change the current element from div to a tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

```
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a1.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a2.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a3.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a4.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a5.html'"></div>

$('.item').each(function() {
    $(this)[0].replace('div', 'a')
})
```

Is it possible to change all the `div` tag to `a` tag? I have tried the code above but not work, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Would you like to change those onclicks into `href` attributes as well?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var onclick = $this.attr('onclick');
    var match = onclick.match(/(location.href=')(.*)(')/);
    $this.replaceWith($('<a/>', {href : match[2], html: this.innerHTML}))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/upAQf/)

Comment: I'd still advocate for moving the contents instead of re-parsing the `innerHTML` - remember that `innerHTML` is a serialized representation of the DOM therefore many valuable properties may be lost, together with all event handlers bound to the descendants.

Comment: So Arun solution will lost all event listener bound to the `div` element and Fabricio won't?

Comment: @CharlesYeung Both lose `div`'s handlers. Difference is that mine doesn't lose handlers bound to the `div`'s descendants, nor descendants' [non-serializable properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11778123/1331430) like `value` and `checked`.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a shot as well:

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith(
        $('<a>', {
            href: /'(.+)'/.exec($(this).attr('onclick'))[1],
            append: $(this).contents()
        })
    );
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yR9WV/1/)

Explanation:

- Creates an anchor element (`<a>`);

  - Sets its `href` to the text between single quotes in the div's `onclick` attribute;
  - Moves all contents (descendant elements and text nodes) from the div to the anchor element, this way preserving their attached event handlers.
- Replaces the div with the created anchor element.

Implications: Any handler bound directly to the `div` previously (e.g. through `.on()` or `addEventListener`) will still be trashed.

Comment: Oh Arun beat me to it, no problem. `=]`

Comment: Why `replaceWith` can accept more then one argument, but I can't see it mentioned in the document http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/, it said `.replaceWith(newContent)` or `.replaceWith(function)`?

Comment: @CharlesYeung Oh it is because of my indentation, I'll re-indent it better. What is being passed to replaceWith is actually just a jQuery object: `$('<a>', {})`

Comment: Why the jQuery object can be made as `$('<a>', {})`, any document for it? I would like to learn it, thanks.

Comment: @CharlesYeung The syntax `$('string representing a single element', attributes)` is documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918792/use-jquery-to-change-an-html-tag). For your example you would do something like this:

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($('<a>' + this.innerHTML + '</a>'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a1.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a2.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a3.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a4.html'"></div>
<div class="item" onclick="location.href='a5.html'"></div>

$('.item').each(function(){
    var onClick = $(this).attr('onclick');
    $(this).replaceWith('<a class="item" onclick="'+onClick+'"></a>');
});
```