# how to obtain html page including all tags and element values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i use document.documentElement.outerHTML and got everything except it does not contain the current state of all input elements (textbox, checkbox, select, radio buttons etc)

i can use jquery to obtain element values and update the html string.  but i hope there is a standard way to do this.  any idea?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("#me").click(function () {
           alert(  document.documentElement.outerHTML )
          });
      });

</script>

 <style type="text/css">
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <form>       
<input id="me" type="submit" value="test" />
<input id="Text1" type="text" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you first do each input like input.setAttribute("value", input.value), the value should show in in outerHTML.

Comment: At a given time, document.documentElement.outerHTML property returns the complete visual representation or state of the document. If you don't have values in the outerHTML string, it means that the value is not present on the textbox or a check box is not actually checked.

Comment: for example:  i have <input type="text" value="">  i run the page and fill out the textbox with "hello".  when i click submit button, i read the page using document.documentElement.outerHTML.  the string contains <input type="text" value=""> but there is no "hello" in the value

Comment: If you have the values, you WILL get those. You can probably create a fiddle and share it so that one can take a look at the problem that you are facing.

Comment: In which function(or event) are you trying to read the page?

Comment: @Prash FYI the `value` property is non-serializable as the `value` attribute corresponds to the `defaultValue` property. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11778123/1331430

Comment: here is the code that i use:

Comment: i read your link (did not understand everything yet).  so are you saying that it is not possible to obtain the complete html string with element values?

Comment: i have updated the question with code if this would help

Comment: What is your end goal with this? Once you have the complete HTML page with entered in values what are you planning on doing with it? If all you want is form keys and values you can set your form's action to a page that can read all values. If you want them all in javascript you can look into jQuery's $("#formID").serialize() function or loop through them or reference them with other methods. In doing this what do you want to accomplish in the end?

Comment: I tried that.  Works the same as outerHTML but again, no value.  The reason I need this so that there would be a record of what a user submitted in html form

Comment: This html form with populated element values will be uploaded to sharepoint for workflow process.  Approvers just want to see the html form with values

Comment: +1 Thanks @FabrícioMatté. Something new. I didn't knew.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the entire page's HTML with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982717/how-do-i-get-the-entire-pages-html-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
alert($('html').html());
```

It will alert the whole [HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.3) except the [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.2).

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what you said in your comments, you really just want the key value pairs of the form submission.

I would first look into using jQuery's `.serialize()`

If jQuery's `.serialize()` isn't what you are looking for, you should be able to reference each value individually, personally I would first identify your form:

```
<form id="formOfStuff">
```

Then in pure javascript you can do something like:

```
var me = formOfStuff.elements["me"].value;
var text1 = formOfStuff.elements["text1"].value;
alert("me=" + me + " text1 = " + text1);
```

or In jQuery:

```
var me = $("#me").val();
var text1 = $("#text1").val();
alert("me=" + me + " text1 = " + text1);
```

The values you entered are part of your POST data and would also be accessible server side on whatever page you are posting to in your form's action.