# jQuery .val() does not work on html chunk?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant figure out, why this code does not work as expected:

```
var $obj = jQuery('<div>xx<input type="text" value="" />xx</div>');
$obj.find('input').val('testing');
console.log($obj.html());
```

The resulting output is without any change - i.e. no change in value. But `append()` and other functions works fine. What could be wrong?

Comment: Setting the `.value` property did never change the `value` attribute that gets serialized by `html()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why aren't some technically serializable input properties serializable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778123/why-arent-some-technically-serializable-input-properties-serializable)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`value` is an **atrribute** of the input dialog.

Doing `.val(...)` changes the value **property** and not the value in the DOM.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/561731) for the differences between properties and attributes.

---

If you wanted to see a **physical** change in the value attribute you *could* do something like this:

```
var $obj = jQuery('<div>xx<input type="text" value="" />xx</div>');
$obj.find('input').attr('value','testing');
console.log($obj.html());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/YsZLt/

Answer (score 0):

The `"value"`-attribute maps to `.defaultValue` property.

There is no attribute that maps to `.value` property. However, on [non-dirty inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11779426/995876)
inputs, you can set the attribute `"value"` (and obviously, `.defaultValue`) and that will be reflected
in the property `.value`.

Since your input is non-dirty, you can do this

```
var $obj = jQuery('<div>xx<input type="text" value="" />xx</div>');
$obj.find('input').prop('defaultValue', 'testing');
console.log($obj.html());
//xx<input type="text" value="testing">xx
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Yes, you should encourage vague and imprecise answers!