# jquery IF behaves differently if i put a alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to disable all elements of my class where my checkbox is not checked.
But even this is checked, my if returns false.

```
$('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {
  if (!$j('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked')){  
    $j('#desc_'+obj.id).attr('disabled','disabled');              
  }        
});
```

But if i put a alert inside the if, its works!

```
$('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {
  if (!$j('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked')){  
    alert($j('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked'));
    $j('#desc_'+obj.id).attr('disabled','disabled');              
  }        
});
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: does this code live in the document ready handler? I bet it is not, and the alert provides a delay in execution.

Comment: fyi, to set the disabled property it's much cleaner to use `.prop('disabled', true_or_false)` instead of fiddling around with attributes

Comment: And it actually works properly when using `.prop()` rather than `.attr()` (.attr() will work initially, but it will then stop working alltogether)

Comment: @KevinB attributes should work fine, it's just that `removeAttr` will be equivalent of `.disabled = false` and any value in `attr` will be equivalent to `.disabled = true`.

Comment: i tried to do `$j('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {       $j('#desc_'+obj.id).prop('disabled', !$j('#'+obj.id).prop('checked'));                  
    });` but it not works too

Comment: @Esailija Yes you are correct, i didn't realize he was using disabled, not checked. Changing the checked attribute is buggy like i described, but not disabled. http://jsfiddle.net/CZKYM/

Comment: @KevinB the checked attribute maps to `.defaultChecked` property, not `.checked` property. The defaultChecked property changes the checked if the input is not dirty. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11779426/995876

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Developers tend to use console.log instead, alert() behaves differently because the DOM wont load in full until AFTER the "OK" button has been clicked on the alert.

Consider using:

```
$('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {
      if (!$j('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked')){  
        console.log($j('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked'));
        $j('#desc_'+obj.id).prop('disabled','disabled');              
      }        
    });
```

For more information and documentation see:

[What is console.log and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

EDIT:

I would also consider using .prop over .attr, the main differences and reasons for this are highlighted here:

[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

There's no point in me re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: No problem at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were referencing jQuery wrong.  Try this :

```
$('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (!$('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked')){  
        $('#desc_'+obj.id).attr('disabled','disabled');              
    }        
});
```

The difference is ..$j(.. vs ..$(..

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that you're code is wrapped in the $(function() { ... }

```
$(function() {
  $('.myClass').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (!$j('input[name='+obj.id+']').is(':checked')){  
      $j('#desc_'+obj.id).attr('disabled','disabled');              
    }        
  });
});
```

Comment: It's unlikely that this is the case due to the fact that `$('.myClass')` selects at least 1 element, unless the code is included after the .myClass element and before the checkbox. Possible, but unlikely.