# getAttribute(attr) method in Java Script returning previous value of attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Unable to get why elem.getAttribute("someAttribute") doesn't return updated value.

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" value="previousValue">
  <script>
    var input = document.body.children[0]
 
    input.value = 'newValue'
 
    alert(input.getAttribute('value')) // 'previousValue', not changed!
  </script>
</body>
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's true that some of the properties on element instances are direct reflections of attributes (the `rel` property directly reflects the `rel` attribute on `link` elements, for instance, and `className` directly reflects the `class` attribute), but this isn't *always* the case.

The `value` property is not a direct reflection of the `value` attribute. It gets its *initial* value from the attribute, but setting it doesn't affect the attribute (which is still available both through `getAttribute` and the `defaultValue` property). (There are others that aren't direct reflections; the `href` property on `a` elements gives you the *absolute* path, but the `href` *attribute* may be a relative path.)

If you want to set the attribute, use `setAttribute`. (And test carefully on any versions of IE you want to support, as Microsoft has a history of getting this wrong.)

Comment: @ShoaibChikate here's another excellent post by TJ which explains HTML attributes vs DOM properties more in-depth: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5884994/1331430 and here's a more technical explanation of this specific behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11779426/1331430

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" value="previousValue">
    <script>
        var input = document.body.children[0];
        input.setAttribute('value', 'newValue');
        alert(input.getAttribute('value')); // 'previousValue', not changed!
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Trying and replacing the code will make me good document writer but not programmer. Hence make your answer better by giving explaination regarding why OP's code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

We can Access Object In JS by Two Types

```
input.value or input[value]
```

**So you have to use second one**

```
    <body>
  <input type="text" value="previousValue">
  <script>
    var input = document.body.children[0]
 
    input[value] = 'newValue'
 
    alert(input.getAttribute('value')) // Now Changed
  </script>
</body>
```